# Contar un cierto carácter y mostrarlo en consola

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-7

Tengo una cadena que dice: "FamiliaFeliz" tengo que contar cuantas F mayúsculas tiene y mostrarlo por consola.

El código que ocupo es el siguiente:

```
function cuentaFs(cadena){
        var n = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < cadena.length -1; i++)
        {
            if(cadena.indexOf('F') != -1)
                n = n + 1;
            return n;
        } 
    } 

    console.log(cuentaFs("FamiliaFeliz"));
```

¿Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el *indexOf* solo retorna la posición de lo primero q encuentra. En tu caso, encuentra la primera f y la retorna. Te dejo un [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798567/7291849) de una respuesta en SO q puede q te ayude

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El **indexOf** retorna la posición del primer elemento q encuentra, pero no sigue analizando. 
Un ejemplo:

```js
let str = 'aaa';
console.log(str.indexOf('a'));
```

Pero por otro lado, puede recibir un segundo parametro, que le indica desde donde tiene que empezar a buscar. Si quieres si o si hacerlo con indexOf, te comparto un enlace de **[una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798477/how-to-find-index-of-all-occurrences-of-element-in-array/20798567#20798567)** en SO que puede q te ayude.
Si no, te dejo una adaptación de tu código usando *charAt* y recorriendo todo el string.

```js
function cuentaFs(cadena){
  var n = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < cadena.length -1; i++){
    if(cadena.charAt(i) == 'F'){
      n += 1;
    }
  } 
  return n;
} 

console.log(cuentaFs("FamiliaFeliz"));
```

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta justamente quería aprender a usar charAt, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas de hacer esto.

Te dejo algunas aportadas en respuestas a la pregunta: [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881085/5587982).

En [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10671743/5587982) se indica también en test de rendimiento entre las distintas posibilidades. Cualquiera de ellas te funcionará.

```js
function cuentaFs(cadena) {
  /* 
     *Esta variable es con fines de automatizar, 
     *se puede recibir en parámetro también, mucho mejor
  */
  var char = 'F';
  
  /* Forma 1*/
  var regEx = new RegExp(char, 'g');
  console.log((cadena.match(regEx) || []).length);
  
   /* Forma 2*/
  console.log(cadena.split(char).length - 1);

  /* Forma 3*/
  console.log([...cadena].filter(l => l === char).length);

}

cuentaFs("FamilifaFeliz");
```

Comment: En la primera forma porque le pones 'g'?

Comment: @PedroÁvila la `g` en expresiones regulares significa *global*  y sirve para indicar que se busque en toda la cadena y devuelve todas las coincidencias. Para más detalles: [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags).

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder leeré el enlace.

Comment: @PedroÁvila, por ejemplo, si quieres que la búsqueda sea *case insensitive*, le pasarías también la bandera `i` al RegEx  y así. Se pueden pasar varias banderas juntas según lo que se necesite.

Comment: Excelente, gracias por la información.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta función.

```js
function cuantasVecesAparece(cadena, caracter){
  var indices = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < cadena.length; i++) {
    if (cadena[i] === caracter) indices.push(i);
  }
             return indices.length;
}
console.log(cuantasVecesAparece('xxx','x'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizando la respuesta de @Vick

podría ser:

```
function find_str(str, to_count){
    return str.split(to_count).length - 1;
}

find_str('FamiliaFeliz', 'F')
```

Comment: Que optimizaste?